# Pattern matching list tail tuple element

Tags: algorithm, f#, compression

I have some Run Length Encoding code that I wrote as an exercise

```
let rle s = 
    s
    |> List.map (fun x -> (x, 1))
    |> List.fold (fun acc x -> 
        match acc with 
            | [] -> [(x, 1)]
            | h::(x, n) -> h::(x, n+1)
            | h -> h::(x, 1)
        )
    |> List.map (fun (x, n) -> 
        match n with
            | 1 -> x.ToString()
            | _ -> x.ToString() + n.ToString()
        )
```

The pattern `h::(x, n) -> h::(x, n+1)` fails to compile.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: @pad Hmm countBy just seems to do a histogram. It doesn't seem to take into account the per element neighborhood conditions.

Comment: You're right. Need a few moments to recall what RLE is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't compile because the second argument for `::` pattern match must be a `list`, but here it is a tuple. In general, you seem to just misunderstand `head` and `tail`. Head is the top element while tail is a list of following elements. Essentially swapping them does the trick:

```
|> List.fold (fun acc x -> 
    match acc with 
        | [] -> [(x, 1)]
        | (x0, n)::t when x0=x -> (x0, n+1)::t
        | t -> (x, 1)::t
    )
    []
```

Note 1: As @pad noticed, `List.fold` requires one more argument, a "bootstrap" accumulator to start with. Obviously, it should be just an empty list, `[]`.
Note 2: you can't directly match `x`. Instead, you bind it to `x0` and compare `x0` with `x`.
Note 3: matching empty list `[]` is not necessary as it would happily work with the last pattern.

Comment: He forgot the second parameter on `List.fold`. You probably should add it too.

Comment: The initial `map` is not needed, either.  And you should note that with this approach (which I agree with), you need to reverse the resulting list if you want its order to match that of the input list.

Answer (score 3):

RLE (for grins)

```
let rle (s: string) = 
  let bldr = System.Text.StringBuilder()
  let rec start = function
    | [] -> ()
    | c :: s -> count (1, c) s
  and count (n, c) = function
    | c1 :: s when c1 = c -> count (n+1, c) s
    | s -> Printf.bprintf bldr "%d%c" n c; start s
  start (List.ofSeq s)
  bldr.ToString()

let s1 = "WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"
let s2 = "12W1B12W3B24W1B14W"

rle s1 = s2 |> printfn "%b" //"true"
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but I was bored and wrote an implementation you might find a bit more instructive -- just step through it with the debugger in Visual Studio or MonoDevelop.

```
let rec private rleRec encoded lastChar count charList =
    match charList with
    | [] ->
        // No more chars left to process, but we need to
        // append the current run before returning.
        let encoded' = (count, lastChar) :: encoded

        // Reverse the encoded list so it's in the correct
        // order, then return it.
        List.rev encoded'

    | currentChar :: charList' ->
        // Does the current character match the
        // last character to be processed?
        if currentChar = lastChar then
            // Just increment the count and recurse.
            rleRec encoded currentChar (count + 1) charList'
        else
            // The current character is not the same as the last.
            // Append the character and run-length for the previous
            // character to the 'encoded' list, then start a new run
            // with the current character.
            rleRec ((count, lastChar) :: encoded) currentChar 1 charList'

let rle charList =
    // If the list is empty, just return an empty list
    match charList with
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: tl ->
        // Call the implementation of the RLE algorithm.
        // The initial run starts with the first character in the list.
        rleRec [] hd 1 tl

let rleOfString (str : string) =
    rle (List.ofSeq str)

let rec printRle encoded =
    match encoded with
    | [] ->
        printfn ""
    | (length, c) :: tl ->
        printf "%i%O" length c
        printRle tl

let printRleOfString = rleOfString >> printRle
```

Pasting the code into F# interactive and using the Wikipedia example for [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding):

```
> printRleOfString "WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW";;
12W1B12W3B24W1B14W
val it : unit = ()
```